# much less + (verb)ing (gerund) agreement/concord

Tags: verbs, gerunds, ing, agreement, academic-writing

Do I need to make sure the gerunds match in the following sentence:

> There is not much attention paid to really **examining** what constitutes this notion, much less **scrutinizing** the received criteria for it.

Comment: The sentence is clunky...my opinion.

Comment: By "match", do you mean have the same number? Why do you think they might have to "match"?

Comment: If you mean by "match" the inclusion of "to" before "scrutinizing", then I agree with you.

Comment: @Cascabel_StandWithUkraine_ Yeah I have this issue a lot, especially when I'm trying to write transition sentences/paragraphs.

Comment: @Shoe I wasn't sure if I should write "scrutinize," "to scrutinize," "to scrutinizing," or "scrutinizing" after "much less." Also not sure whether what follows "much less" always agrees with the rest of the sentence, based on these examples I found online:  (i) I'm not used to having a phone in the house, much less carrying a cell phone. (ii) Dean only had a brief glance at the rider, not enough to even tell if the helmeted figure was a man or a woman, much less recognize the person. (iii) It wasn't her intent to solicit sympathy from anyone, much less her paying guests.

Comment: @zey yil. Again, it depends what you mean by "agree". In each of your three examples, I would repeat _to/from_: "much less to carrying a cell phone/ much less to recognize the person/ much less from her paying guests". I think this removes all potential ambiguity and is thus a courtesy to the reader. I would not see this as a general rule, however. It doesn't work to repeat the "to" in the sentence: "He didn't know how to boil an egg, much less (*to) cook a three-course meal."...

Comment: And it's a more complex issue in sentences such as "He didn't apologize for his mistake, much less take responsibility for it"-  where it is ungrammatical to repeat the auxilary "didn't".

Comment: _Much less_ is an idiom with very similar meaning, usage, and restrictions as _let alone_, which is extensively covered in [Fillmore, Kay, and O'Connor 1988](https://user.phil-fak.uni-duesseldorf.de/~filip/fillmore+88.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

It would not be inappropriate to delete the second preposition 'to' with a second ing-clause with the same object:

- *There has not been much attention paid to reading, much less [Ø] really getting to understand, the document.*

But with different objects, omitting the second 'to' sounds at best unnatural:

- ?/?? *There has not been much attention paid to reading the document, much less really getting to understand the complex recommendations it makes.*